# Show more/less link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with text inside it. The requirement is that if the text is more than 3 lines long then hide the rest of the text and show a "more.." link. (the more link must be appended to the visible text, and not show up on a new line)

Clicking on the more link will make the div expand to show the entire block of text, and the "more.." link will change to "less...".

Clicking the less will collapse the text back to 3 lines again, and the more link will reappear.

This should only happen if the text is longer than 3 lines.

I tried using the number of characters to append the more link, but this becomes a problem when it comes to responsive design. The users shouldn't see more than 3 lines of text even on phones, tablets.

This is what I have so far.

```
$('.notesDiv').each(function(div) {
                var content = $(this).html();

                if (content.length > 550) {
                    content = content.substr(0, 550);
                    content += ' <a href="#" class="showMore">More...</a>';

                    $(this).html(content);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Try this: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-shortened-text-show-more-link-jquery/

Comment: I know this question is closed, but I created a fiddle for you to do this, see: http://jsfiddle.net/NwAL8/ - it uses approximate line height to work out the minimal height, you should specify the actual line height in your CSS for a better calculation.

Comment: I have added a sample of my code & hopefully that'll get the question re-opened.

Comment: ExtPro that's exactly what I was looking for. Hopefully, the question will be re-opened and then I'll mark your reply as the answer. I just assumed my code is kinda irrelevant because its no where close to what I'm trying to accomplish so no point posting it. Never again lol.

Comment: @ExtPro Please post your comment as an answer so I can give you the deserved credit for helping me accomplish what I wanted. :)

Comment: @Mogambo- I've added the answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NwAL8)

HTML

```
<div class='item'>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
```

jQuery

```
function collapse(item) {

    var lineHeight = item.css('line-height') !== 'normal' ? parseInt(item.css('line-height')) : parseInt(item.css('font-size')) * 3.7;
    var height = item.height();
    if (lineHeight < height) {
        item.css({
            'height': lineHeight + 'px',
            overflow: 'hidden'
        });
        item.children('a.toggle').length == 0 && item.append("<a href='#' class='toggle'>(more)</a>");
    }
}

$('div.item').each(function () {
    collapse($(this));
});


$('a.toggle').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var toggle = $(this);
    var item = toggle.parent('div');
    if (toggle.text() == '(more)') {
        toggle.text('(less)');
        item.css({
            'overflow': 'auto',
            'height': 'auto'
        });
    } else {
        toggle.text('(more)');
        collapse(item);
    }
});
```

CSS

```
div.item {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:300px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    position:relative;
    min-height:10px;
}
a.toggle {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:white;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```